# Международная телефония с виртуальной АТС

Tags: sip, телефония

Хотел бы у вас спросить совета. Ищу сейчас для компании в которой работаю Международную АТС, с возможностью покупки международных номеров, нормальной связью по разным странам, виртуальной АТС, и конечно же интеграцией с amoCRM.
Идеальный вариант, чтобы связь хорошая была и в РФ, чтобы перевести все отделы компании на эту телефонию, сейчас на весь букет атсок с операторами тратим не меньше 3-5к долларов.